# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for two metrics to have same open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

There are couple of independent conditions like one being scalar multiple of another, or if $$d_p(x,y)=(x^p+y^p)^{1/p}$$ then all $d_ps$ and $d_qs.$ which guarantee that open sets are same under these different metrics in same space. Is the some necessary and sufficient condition that guarantees this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Topological_equivalence) for an extensive description. The most obvious one is the following:

> For any $x \in X$, $r \in \mathbb R$ with $r>0$, there are $r',r''>0$ such that $B_{r'}(x) \subseteq \tilde{B}_r(x)$ and $\tilde{B}_{r''}(x) \subseteq B_r(x)$.

Here, $B_r(x) = \{y\in X:d(x,y) < r\}$, $\tilde{B}_r(x) = \{y\in X:\tilde{d}(x,y) < r\}$.

That is, given any ball in one metric, there are balls in the other metric **containing** and **contained within** this ball, centred at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

Some metrics $d$ and $\delta$ on $X$ define the same topology on $X$ (that is, their open sets coincide) when, for every $x$ in $X$, the map $X\to\mathbb R$, $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous at $x$ with respect to $\delta$ and the map $X\to\mathbb R$, $y\mapsto \delta(x,y)$ is continuous at $x$ with respect to $d$.

For a counterexample, consider the Euclidean metric and the discrete metric on $\mathbb R^n$.